# Javascript - Won't work for second date range/won't reload on button press

Tags: javascript

I am having issues getting my script to work.

It will work for date range 1, but not for date range 2. And what makes things more peculiar is that it won't reload after each button press.

```html
<div class="costs">
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker" id="date" name="date" value="Choose when you want to go" style="background:#fff;"></p>
<select name="roomtype" id="roomtype" value="What room type would you like?">
    <option value="Classic">Classic</option>
    <option value="Luxury Room">Luxury Room</option>
    <option value="Suite">Suite</option>
</select>
<select name="night" id="night" value="How many nights are you going for?">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select name="room" id="room" value="How many people to a room?">
    <option value="Single">Single</option>
    <option value="Double">Double</option>
</select>
<div>
Cost:<br>
<button onclick="checkCosts()">Get Cost</button>
<p id="cost">Choose a date and press the "Get Cost" button, to find out how much it will cost for your next African Golf Safari trip</p>
</div>
    <script>
        function checkCosts() {
var date = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value;
var roomtype = document.getElementsByName("roomtype")[0].value;
var night = document.getElementsByName("night")[0].value;
var room = document.getElementsByName("room")[0].value;
var month = date.substring(0, 2);
var year = date.substring(8, 10);
var day = date.substring(4,6);
var time = month.concat(year);
var fulldate = parseInt(day.concat(time));
var inttime = parseInt(time);
//=================================
//Date Range 1
//Check earliest date
if(inttime >= 415){
//Check latest date
if(inttime <= 915){
//Classic Roomtype
if(roomtype == "Classic"){
//Nights Double
if(room = "Double"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,480";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,450";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,415";}
}
//Nights Single
if(room = "Single"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,575";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,510";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,440";}
}
}
//End
//Luxury Roomtype
if(roomtype == "Luxury"){
//Nights
if(room = "Double"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,620";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,580";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,535";}
}
//Nights Single
if(room = "Single"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,830";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,760";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,685";}
}
}
//End
//Suite Roomtype
if(roomtype == "Suite"){
//Nights
if(room = "Double"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,815";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,770";}
}
//Nights Single
if(room = "Single"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,300";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,235";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,145";}
}
}
//End
}
}
}
//=================================
//Date Range 2
//Check earliest date
if(inttime >= 1015){
//Check latest date
if(inttime <= 316){
//Classic Roomtype
if(roomtype == "Classic"){
//Nights Double
if(room = "Double"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,480";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,450";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,415";}
}
//Nights Single
if(room = "Single"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,575";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,510";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,440";}
}
}
//End
//Luxury Roomtype
if(roomtype == "Luxury"){
//Nights
if(room = "Double"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,620";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,580";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,535";}
}
//Nights Single
if(room = "Single"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,830";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,760";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,685";}
}
}
//End
//Suite Roomtype
if(roomtype == "Suite"){
//Nights
if(room = "Double"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,815";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,770";}
}
//Nights Single
if(room = "Single"){
if(night == "3"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,300";}
if(night == "5"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,235";}
if(night == "7"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,145";}
}
}
//End
}
}
                  </script>
Find on: https://jsfiddle.net/zo7xr42j/
```

(the `//=========` is just so I could separate stuff)

The reason I am under the assumption that the button should reload the price is that it works like that on every other page (which uses similar code)
which can be found

```
http://www.africangolfsafari.com/mountains-wine/
```

Comment: please add code to the question so that we can see what you are talking about. The fiddle is a good point but your question should be readable even without

Comment: It is a little long, so I didn't add it, but it's added now :)

Comment: try to extract the relevant section. Learn here [how to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Problem is, I don't know what the issue is, so it could be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
        //Date Range 2
    //Check earliest date
    if (inttime >= 1015) {
```

Is not in the function `checkCosts` so when the browser read the code, the var doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Sometimes you miss the most obvious things. Thanks :) However, adding it in (moving the function's closing bracket), still didn't work :/

Comment: I used the Tidy function of JSfiddle to see is easily

Comment: the first half works, (date range 1) but the second half (date range 2), doesn't. No errors (syntax), and nothing showing in the console on chrome

Comment: Nevermind... I looked at it again after being a complete idiot... 316 (march 2016) is less than 1015 (october 2015)